# Can;t figure out why java is ignoring my print statement after the if else statement

Tags: java

A software company sells a package that retails for $99. Quantity discounts are given according to the following table:

```
    Quantity Discount
    10-19 20%
    20-49 30%
    50-99 40%
    100 or more 50%
```

Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of packages purchased. The program should then display the amount of the discount (if any) and the total amount of the purchase after the discount. For instance, to calculate 20% of a value N, you can use the formula:

```
`(20 / 100.0) * N (or 0.2 * N)`.
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SoftwareSales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaring variables
        int qtyPurchased;
        double discount;
        int cost = 99;
        double total;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of packages purchased: ");
        qtyPurchased = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        
        if (qtyPurchased >= 10 && qtyPurchased <= 19) {
            discount = (0.2 * qtyPurchased);
        } else if (qtyPurchased >= 20 && qtyPurchased <= 49) {
            discount = (0.3 * qtyPurchased);
        } else if (qtyPurchased >= 50 && qtyPurchased <= 99) {
            discount = (0.4 * qtyPurchased);
        } else if (qtyPurchased >= 100) {
            discount = (0.5 * qtyPurchased);
        } else if (qtyPurchased < 10) {
            discount = 0 * qtyPurchased;
        } else
            discount = 0;
        
        total = ((cost * qtyPurchased) - discount);
        System.out.print("Your discount is: " + discount + "\n"
                + "Your total is: " + total);
        
    }
}
    
    
    **************************************************
    
    Following is the error I get:
    
    Given the following was entered from the keyboard:
    0
    you displayed:
    Enter◦number◦of◦packages◦purchased:◦
    **instead of:
    Enter◦number◦of◦packages◦purchased:◦Your◦discount◦is:◦$0.00⏎
    Your◦total◦is:◦$0.00⏎**
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. `Enter number of packages purchased: 0
Your discount is: 0.0
Your total is: 0.0`

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the the following line. It isn't needed and prompts for input that isn't used.

```
  keyboard.nextLine();
```

You can also put this is a loop, checking for input until a negative value is entered.

```
public class SoftwareSales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaring variables
        int qtyPurchased;
        double discount;
        int cost = 99;
        double total;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter number of packages purchased: ");
            qtyPurchased = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (qtyPurchased < 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (qtyPurchased >= 10 && qtyPurchased <= 19) {
                discount = (0.2 * qtyPurchased);
            } else if (qtyPurchased >= 20 && qtyPurchased <= 49) {
                discount = (0.3 * qtyPurchased);
            } else if (qtyPurchased >= 50 && qtyPurchased <= 99) {
                discount = (0.4 * qtyPurchased);
            } else if (qtyPurchased >= 100) {
                discount = (0.5 * qtyPurchased);
            } else if (qtyPurchased < 10) {
                discount = 0 * qtyPurchased;
            } else
                discount = 0;
            
            total = ((cost * qtyPurchased) - discount);
            System.out.print("Your discount is: " + discount + "\n"
                    + "Your total is: " + total);
        }
        System.out.print("Done");
    }
}
```